# Using EasyModbusTCP Java, how do I read my registers as unsigned values?

Tags: java, modbus, modbus-tcp

I am trying out [easyModbus TCP](http://easymodbustcp.net/), to read in holding registers of a ADAM 6017 analog unit. I am using the [example client code](http://easymodbustcp.net/java-modbus-tcp-client-example) to get familiar with this library. The problem I seem to be having is I need the values of the registers to be read as unsigned but it gives me signed values back. I have 3.3548 Volts attached to the unit, and the scale is set to 0-5v, and it outputs -10781 from the ADC. Here is what I have written:

```
package modbus.logger;
import de.re.easymodbus.modbusclient.*;
import java.lang.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Michael Haire
 * SJVAPCD
 */
public class ModbusLogger {

        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           float volt;
           int Input;
           int x = 1;
           float input;
        ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("192.168.1.201",502);
        try
        {   while(x>0){
            modbusClient.Connect();
            System.out.print("Raw ADC Value: ");System.out.println(modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1)[0]);
                        Input =  modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters(0, 1)[0];
                        System.out.print("Input: ");System.out.println(Input);
                        input = (float) Input;
                        volt = (float) ((input / 65536)*5.0);
                        System.out.print("Voltage: ");System.out.printf("%f%n" , volt);System.out.println("");

        }}
        catch (Exception e){        
        }   
        }
   }
```

What should I do to get an unsigned value?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken the manual of your device:

https://www.i-components.fi/pdf/76-ADAM-6066-CE.pdf

says (page 268) that your channel 0 analog value should be in **register 40001**.

That means you should be using `modbusClient.ReadHoldingRegisters` instead of input registers.

Sometimes it's useful to check your device before you get busy writing code. To do that you can use modpoll (https://www.modbusdriver.com/modpoll.html) or something like QModMaster (https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/).

Comment: I am using [Simply Modbus](www.simplymodbus.ca) as my interface outside of the program. I already tried the holding register line before and it give me a signed value, once I go above about 2.7V the output goes negative. And I am aware of the Adam 6017 manual since I work with these units regularly.

Comment: With a signed value an output of 32767 I am positive but above that it goes negative. I need and unsigned value for this to work, because with it unsigned I get the full 65565 output range

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm no Java expert but apparently, everything is signed in Java. I think you can just convert to unsigned. Take a look here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Java_Data_Type/0160__Java_Unsigned_Data_Type.htm

Comment: Java might be signed but the output from the Modbus unit should be read as unsigned.

Comment: But have you tried to convert using Byte.toUnsignedInt(); once you read the register?